# How to limit the running splits per task in trino?

Tags: optimization, trino

The case is:

Someone run some big tasks, which running splits are more than 20,000 and total splits are more than 1,000,000.

Then the trino cluster has no resource for other tasks.

Other users will not get the result, and finally timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reduce [task.max-drivers-per-task](https://trino.io/docs/current/admin/properties-task.html#task-max-drivers-per-task).

Comment: I have done it with task.max-drivers-per-task=15,000. But some queries still run above 100,000+